# Подготовка к собеседованию - алгоритмические задачи

Tags: алгоритм

Для собеседования на работу нужно в течение пары недель  подготовится к решению задач типа таких
[image]

Подскажите учебники / сайты где бы разбиралось решение таких задач?

Comment: первая задача - это поиск в графе (алгоритмизировав - в направленном графе найти такую вершину, в которую все ребра указывают, но ни одно не выходит). Вторая задача - поиск максимума в массиве, классическая NP задача - [вот решение](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_average_segment). На этом же сайте есть много других хороших вещей.

Answer (score -1):

**Алгоритм:**
Разобьем последовательность на пары, и будем искать звезду в паре.
Например, есть последовательность 1,2,3,4
Вызовем `first_knows_second` 4ре раза:

```
first_knows_second(1,2)
first_knows_second(2,1)
first_knows_second(3,4)
first_knows_second(4,3)
```

Звезда в паре не найдена тогда, когда оба вызова, например `first_knows_second(1,2)` и `first_knows_second(2,1)` дали истину, или оба дали ложь.
Вспомним условие: о звезде знают все, она же не знает ни о ком. Т.е. если оба в паре знают друг о друге, то ни один из них не является звездой. И так же, если оба не знают друг о друге, то они звездами не являются.

Если в паре есть один элемент, который не знает о другом, а другой о нем знает, то выделяем этого не знающего как звезду.

Итак, мы сделали N вызовов `first_knows_second` и нашли некоторое количество звезд. Для худшего варианта это будет **N/2**.

Эту процедуру надо повторять до тех пор, пока не останется всего два элемента. Для двух элементов можно сделать только один вызов.

Итак, мы имеем последовательность (для худшего варианта):
`N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8...` до тех пор, пока n деленная на что-то не будет равно 2 (внимание! это ограничение важно для понимания следующих строк!).

Чем больше N тем длиннее последовательность. `N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ....` будет равно N при бесконечном знаменателе. Т.е. при бесконечно большом числе N наша последовательность `N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8...` будет равна `2*N`. Что и является ответом.